# Update MySQL if checkbox Unchecked

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using the script found here to update my database if a box is checked.
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4592766/revisions

It works if I check an unchecked box.

However, I can't seem to get it working if I uncheck a checked box. It will not update the database.

Here is the modified code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    var isSel = this.checked;
    var isNotSel = this.unchecked; //added
     $.ajax({
        url: 'file.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            id : this.id,
            isSelected : isSel,
            isNotSelected : isNotSel // added

        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('updated');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
});
```

This is the code showing the checkboxes (created from database):

```
if($status == 'pending')    
{ echo '<input type="checkbox" name="status" id='.$submission_id.' >' .     
$task_name . '<br>'; }
if($status == 'done')
{ echo '<input type="checkbox" name="status" id='.$submission_id.' checked>' 
. $task_name . '<br>'; }
```

Here is the code for file.php

```
if ($_POST && isset($_POST['isSelected'])) {

$sql = 'UPDATE ft_form_53 SET status = "done" WHERE submission_id = ' . $_POST['id'];

// check if the query was executed
if(mysql_query($sql, $link)){
   // everything is Ok, the data was inserted
   print(1);    
} else {
   // error happened
   print(0);
}
}

if ($_POST && isset($_POST['isNotSelected'])) {

$sql = 'UPDATE ft_form_53 SET status = "pending" WHERE submission_id = ' . $_POST['id'];

// check if the query was executed
if(mysql_query($sql, $link)){
   // everything is Ok, the data was inserted
   print(1);    
} else {
   // error happened
   print(0);
}
}
```

No error message is thrown. Any ideas?

Comment: you are using `click(function()` better if you use `change(function()`

Comment: Sorry, still learning. I assumed that error: function() in the JS and else {
   // error happened
   print(0); in the php would show something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. Thanks to [shehary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4258081/shehary) for the **click** to **change** modification and to [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) for the **!this.checked** tip. I ended up using two separate scripts but it works :) Thanks again to all!

The one below is for uncheck.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    var isNotSel = !this.checked;
     $.ajax({
        url: 'file.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            id : this.id,
            isNotSelected : isNotSel

        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('updated');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Actually, `click` is just fine for checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks. I also noticed that if I click on one checkbox then another without waiting a few seconds, only the first is written to the database. Is there a way to prevent another checkbox from being checked until the first has finished writing? Gray/lock out the screen for a second or two?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var isNotSel = this.unchecked;
```

to

```
var isNotSel = !isSel;
```

or

```
var isNotSel = !this.checked;
```

Checkboxes don't have an `unchecked` property. They have a boolean `checked` property (`true` if checked, `false` if not). And you've already grabbed that into `isSel`, so...